# Proof $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, then $o(g(n))\subsetneq O(g(n))$.

Tags: notation

Proof,
Let $g: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ then  $o(g(n))\subsetneq O(g(n))$.

This is my idea:
$g\in O(g)$ but $g\notin o(g)$.

Or
$A\subsetneq B\iff A\subseteq B$ and $A\ne B$.

Is that the correct proof?

Comment: This is not a proof. You have to show that every $f \in o(g(n))$ is also in $O(g(n))$, but there is at least one function in the latter set that is not in the former.

Comment: If $g$ is allowed to have positive, negative, and zero values, it is probably not wise to talk about $O(g)$ or $o(g)$.

Comment: f(n)=O(g(n))                                                                        if f(n) ≤ c.g(n) for all n > k                                                  C and k are positiv                                                 f(n)/g(n) ≤ c for all n > k                                         O(g(n)) = {f(n) | ∃ C > 0 and n0 ∈ N, so |f(n)| ≤ C |g(n)| for all n ≥ n0.                                                o(g(n))={f(n) | for all C > 0 exists n0 ∈ N, so |f(n) < C|g(n)| for all n>n0.                                                           Is that right? I did my best ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is only half done.

You proved that $A\neq B$. You still need to prove that $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: f(n)=O(g(n))     

    if f(n) ≤ c.g(n) for all n > k

    C and k are positiv

     f(n)/g(n) ≤ c for all n > k

      O(g(n)) = {f(n) | ∃ C > 0 and n0 ∈ N, so 
      |f(n)| ≤ C |g(n)| for all n ≥ n0.

      o(g(n))={f(n) | for all C > 0 exists n0 ∈ N, 
      so |f(n) < C|g(n)| for all n>n0.

      Is that right? I did my best ;)